# GWT Editor Framework, what is the correct Editor Interface to provides Editor support to this complex use case

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

I have a TabPanel wdget that will have an unknow number of TabItems widgets each of them will have an unknow number of FieldSet classes each of them implements

```
Editor<Foo>
```

TabItem class has a method to add a FieldSet and TabPanel has a method to add a TabItem.

I would like to know what kind of Editor should I implement on the TabItem class or/and on the TabPanel class in order to provide a FooEditor that  will hanlder all the FieldSets as a whole.

I mean when I define:

```
 myDriver implements SimpleBeanEditorDriver<Foo, FooEditor>
```

I need that FooEditor will see each FieldSet as a sub-editor.

Any help will be appreciated.
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

In your case I believe you would have a regular (TabPanel implements Editor< TabItem>) which you use to edit the normal fields TabItem, then within that Editor you would have (FieldSets implements ListEditor< FieldSet, FieldSetEditor>), where field set is an editor such as (FieldSetEditor implements Editor< FieldSet>).

You would need a driver for each type editor, I recommend googling around for examples of ListEditor and taking a look at the dev guide:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding what you are saying. TabItem is a widget so TabPanel implements Editor<TabItem> has no sense to me.Each of the FieldSets are already Editors, so Having a FieldSets class that implements ListEditor<FieldSet, FieldSetEditor> also has no sense.In my use case the only Domain Model Object I want to edit is Foo, and each FieldSet is an Editor<Foo> that edits subset of properties of Foo.